# Newsletter2go ruby API client authorisation with get_token method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, authorization, newsletter2go

Good day!
Can you please give me an example of authentication request with ruby newsletetr2go API client.
I can't figure it out.
I can connect to API using direct requests like `RestClient.post "#{link}/oauth/v2/token", credentials, default_header`
In credentials I use my `username`, `password` and `grant_type`, converted to json format

In default header I use `content_type: 'application/json'` and `authorization: "Basic #{Base64.strict_encode64(ENV['NEWSLETTER2GO_AUTH_KEY'])}"`
And it works fine. But when I try to use newsletter2go `get_token` method all I receive is "BAD REQUEST" error.

I'm using initializer to configure `SwaggerClient` like this:

```
SwaggerClient.configure do |config|
  # Configure OAuth2 access token for authorization: OAuth
  config.password   = ENV['NEWSLETTER2GO_PASSWORD']
  config.username   = ENV['NEWSLETTER2GO_USERNAME']
  config.api_key    = ENV['NEWSLETTER2GO_AUTH_KEY']
end
```

After that I use newsletter2go api method call

```
SwaggerClient::AuthorizationApi.new.get_token("https://nl2go.com/jwt")
```

Seems everything is correct, but error `"BAD REQUEST"` happens all the time.

I followed the instructions, install `swagger_client` with ruby extentions in github, and newsletter2go methods are now available from my rails environment.
If I grab `access_token` manually and add it to my initializer, then do some requests like `SwaggerClient::ListApi.new.get_lists` it gives me a proper response with `status 200` and `list_ids`

But `SwaggerClient::AuthorizationApi.new.get_token("https://nl2go.com/jwt")` does not work and this is the issue.
Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that your `ENV` variables are populated with the correct values?

Comment: I use them to make manual requests as well. The difference is that I use "Basic #{Base64.strict_encode64(ENV['NEWSLETTER2GO_AUTH_KEY'])}" }
But I tryed both options, encoded and exact - and both gave me same error. Looks like the problem is that it do not grab API_KEY at all.

Comment: Does `printenv | grep NEWSLETTER2GO_AUTH_KEY` contain a value?

Comment: No, but all other environment variables don't displays as well. I think it's a different thing: rails envs and linux envs, are they?

Comment: It depends where you set the env vars, how are you setting these vars?

Comment: They are in config/application.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the reason why Newsletter2Go API ruby client does not grab api_key value. For some reason it's hardcoded to setup basic auth token which stands from username and password packed.
Here is code from

`module SwaggerClient
  class Configuration`

```
# Gets Basic Auth token string
def basic_auth_token
  'Basic ' + ["#{username}:#{password}"].pack('m').delete("\r\n")
end

# Returns Auth Settings hash for api client.
def auth_settings
  {
    'OAuth' =>
      {
        type: 'oauth2',
        in: 'header',
        key: 'Authorization',
        value: "Bearer #{access_token}"
      },
    'Basic' =>
      {
        type: 'basic',
        in: 'header',
        key: 'Authorization',
        value: basic_auth_token
      },
  }
end
```